# How to center <input> horizontally in a <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have attempted multiple times, with multiple different possible solutions from around Stack Overflow to accomplish this task, yet frustratingly, I cannot seem to be able to center the input box in the div.

My code essentially looks like this at the moment:

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <input type='text'>
</div>
```

As of the moment, the word "Title" is centered on the screen, but the input box is still on the left hand side.

Is there any way to be able to center the  horizontally in the div?

Comment: add style css text-align:center in parent Div

Comment: the input box is `display: inline-block` by default. Change that to `display: block` and use `margin: auto` to center it.

Comment: why not just put `text-align:center` on the parent div - would be the simplest solution given the h1 is also centred?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a vertical align?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to the container `div`.

**Note**: centring the `h1` becomes unnecessary after applying `flex`

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <input type='text'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that has done it. I'm not sure why I wasn't able to do it before, but this most definitely works! I'll mark it as the answer as soon as it will let me do so.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 input[type="text"] {
             display: block;
             margin : 0 auto;
        }
```

Example: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rjLLo8gr/)

Answer (score 3):

Display block. input elements are inline.

```
<input type='text' style="display:block; margin : 0 auto;">
```